# WPF Display Mouse Coordinates on canvas using a tooltip

Tags: wpf, canvas, tooltip, mouse

Can someone point me in the right track for displaying the XY mouse position on a Canvas using a tooltip?
I would like to drag the mouse and the tooltip update the position as the user moves the mouse. I tried doing this programmatically using the mouse enter to update the tooltip but was failing to get anything to show up. Thanks

Comment: You clearly didn't search before asking... [Binding the tooltip to the mouse position](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c421935-ce88-4592-bbd7-98f371632b41/binding-the-tooltip-to-the-mouse-position).

Comment: This doesn't display the xy postion, just moves the tooltip to where the mouse was.

Comment: [Mouse Handling in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/Mouse.html).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested in the solution...

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tt.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;
        tt.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + 10;
        tt.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y + 10;
        tt.Content = "X-Coordinate: " + e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + "\n" + "Y-Coordinate: " + e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y;
    }
```